# Rails each discard item nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, each

I have the next array

```
[nil,nil,object,object,nil,object]
```

are there any way to do an each who omit the nil values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) to remove `nil` values:

```
[nil, nil, object, object, nil, object].compact
#=> [object, object, object]
```

In combination with `each`:

```
[nil, nil, object, object, nil, object].compact.each do |obj|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: `compact` will also not modify the initial array, so i guess that would be the best solution here

Answer (score 1):

`reject` also is a good method to remove `nil` values from ex. array

```
> [1,2,3,nil,nil,3,nil,3,nil].reject { |x| x.nil? }
=> [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

in a block you can write more code to better operating on data.